# Excessive Memory Usage in my App

Tags: dart

We have a Dart application that is using what we believe to be excessive memory once it is loaded. After refreshing the main app page and then forcing garbage collection, Observatory shows that the Old Generation size continues to grow, meaning that things aren't being de-referenced.

The primary consumer of space is the `_List` class in the dart.core library. From what I can tell, this class appears to be used by the VM to store all kinds of things, most of which may be out of our direct control. Observatory isn't very helpful in understanding what is allocating memory to `_List` instances, since there are nearly a million instances. I'm also not convinced that Observatory itself doesn't contribute to the memory footprint of the app that it's trying to monitor.

Can anyone tell me how the `_List` class is used so that we can begin to address what is allocating so much memory?

Comment: That surely depends on your application - I guess.

Comment: How big is your app? What is it's nature and what does it do? What do you regard as 'excessive' memory usage? What numbers are you actually seeing? With regards to use of _List, I should think it's libraries that you are using that are creating those instances if your code is not, not the VM.

Comment: a million instances? then you shoud definately save it to disk and read it. is possible use cache.

Comment: _List is the default implementation of [List](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.List). Perhaps your application is leaking lists, creating a large number of them, or lists with a large number of items. Perhaps post a message to the [mailing list](http://dartlang.org/mailing-list) asking for advice on how to track down memory leaks.